# Salesforce MVP Nominations 2022 - 2023

Tags: discussion, mvp

### Salesforce MVP 2023 Nominations Are Open

[Nominations](https://nominations.salesforcemvps.com/s/) for the Salesforce MVP Class of 2023 are now open. Feel free to nominate those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be users or moderators or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

Read this Blog:- [Nominate Your Trailblazer Community Mentors and Champions to Be a Salesforce MVP](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/mvp-nominations-2023/?utm_campaign=amer_trl&utm_content=Salesforce%20Trailhead,Trailhead_&utm_medium=organic_social&utm_source=facebook,linkedin)